# Bootstrap - How to add text to Nav Bar Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I need to add some text to dropdown menu on my navigation bar, but as I'm new to bootstrap I'm failing to do that.

Here is code:

[image]

The text, I want to display is in white (thats why I selected it)

But on "mobile-version" it's displaying like this:

[image]

So how do I add text to dropdown menus without breaking design?

Comment: Can you show code in jsfiddle?

Comment: I can't properly put code to jsfiddle, it's not displaying dropdown menu

Comment: probably the css is not responsive..please learn more about responsive css.

Comment: Try putting your code in http://bootply.com/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's easily replicated and that it's supposed to have a `float-right` for it to work. I added the style `margin-left:15px;` onto `navbar-text` and it worked, but make sure to ONLY do this for the smaller media query.

Comment: Maybe I just need to go with `<li class='disabled'><a href='#'>Text</a></li>` but that's not exactly what I want

Comment: @AigarsCibuļskis Updated answer. You need to add a custom style for smaller media query.